# how can i write a trigger that compare between two tables in phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger, foreign-key

I have two tables that has rows that have same values.

I want to write a trigger that will check for mypin in debtors tables and if mypin exists in debtors it fills the debtor row in the users table to have a value of 1 and if mypin does not exist in debtors table it fill the debtor row in users table to be 0.

```
debtors table
`debtor`, `myPIN`,
```

```
Users table
 `debtor`,`myPIN`
```

A db<>fiddle can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7bd5ba34caf88fe35c255142b6eebe42)

Comment: Welcome to the site, please post create table statements and insert statements (or create an https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 or similar).

Comment: As @Lennart says - we need DDL (`CREATE TABLE` statements), DML (`INSERT INTO` statements), some sample data, your desired result and finally, the logic you used to get that final result. There are a few articles on my profile on how to ask questions here - you might want to take a look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @Lennart i have posted the two table fields

Comment: @Lennart i have created the two table in the link you gave me (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41cd9c97502da45065e6370c52d33fd7)

Comment: Good, but I'm still having trouble understanding what you want to do (for example, there's no column named mypin and what column do you want to set to 0/1 in the users table). Can you add sample data, and what the expected result should be?

Comment: @Lennart i have changed now there is column named mypin

Comment: the column that i want to set 0/1 is `debtor` column.so it is like this when the user is registering in the `users table`  and  `mypin` exists in debtors table it input a value in the `debtor` column in users table and if mypin does not exist in debtors table it input a 0 value in `debtor` column in user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example. You should make deptor and mypin 
columns not null, or you will have to deal with possible nulls there:

```
delimiter //
create trigger before_insert_users
before insert on users
for each row
begin
    IF ( EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM debtors
            WHERE debtors.myPIN = NEW.myPIN
         )
    )    
    THEN
        SET NEW.debtor = 1;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.debtor = 0;
    END IF;
end //
```

Note that you will need a delete trigger on debtor as well (if myPIN can change you need an update trigger in each table as well.

Comment: it is giving me an error when i write the trigger in mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: i have written the trigger but it not checking the exist of my pin `BEGIN
    IF ( EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM debtors
            WHERE debtors.myPIN = NEW.myPIN
         )
    )    
    THEN
        SET NEW.debtor = 1;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.debtor = 0;
    END IF;
END`

Comment: it is not checking the exist of `mypin` in debtors table and it is not inserting the value 1 in `debtor` column if mypin exist in debtors table

Comment: I added the example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=dUSp2e3z42 I'm afraid I don't have a clue about phpmyadmin

Comment: i have written the trigger but it is giving `0` values  whether your `mypin` exist in debtors or not .even those that do not exist in debtors it is giving them zero.what could be the problem.

Comment: Please explain what the expected result is in my example. Since you refuse to provide a single example, this is just guesswork

Comment: it lastly it worked perfectly after struggling thank you man.now i will have to write another trigger to cater for update when one clear the balance in `debtors table` so that it will update the `debtor` one value and it will update `users table`

Comment: ho w can i write an update trigger for this [reference to this] (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239028/how-can-i-write-an-update-trigger-between-two-tables?noredirect=1#comment471490_239028)

Comment: What have you tried, and what error did you get?

Comment: this is what i have tied  but its not updating what could be the problem ```DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_debt_defaulters` AFTER INSERT ON `defaulters`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF ( EXISTS (
            SELECT DISTINCT `KRAPIN` FROM defaulters WHERE `Debt_Amount` = '0'
           )   
       )
        THEN
            UPDATE users 
            SET users.debtor = '0'
            WHERE KRAPIN = NEW.KRAPIN;
        END IF;
END```

Comment: thanks answering my call .but now the update trigger is working as expected thanks man.  ```DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_debt_defaulters` AFTER UPDATE ON `defaulters`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF ( EXISTS (
            SELECT DISTINCT `KRAPIN` FROM defaulters WHERE defaulters.Debt_Amount = '0'
           )   
       )
        THEN
            UPDATE users 
            SET users.debtor = '0'
            WHERE KRAPIN = NEW.KRAPIN;
        END IF;
END```

Comment: Good, FWIW, since you only looking for the existence of something, distinct has no purpose

Comment: So I should remove it .what should I replace it with